# Single method class - pass dependcies to constructor or method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a very simple class that has a single method.

The method needs two objects passed to it to prepare an output and return the output.

Should the class be instantiated with these two objects passed to the constructor, or should those be passed to method when being called?

Currently I can see that the method will always be called only once per request and always with the same objects passed to it.

Comment: Without more context it is hard to say which approach makes most sense.

Comment: It depends. Generally, passing arguments is a very cheap operation in Java (it's just a pointer). But as Henry said, we need more context

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors involved, but in general, the constructor should take arguments for configuration (if any configuration is needed), and the actual input should be passed to a method.  Methods should be the "verbs" or "actions" in an object-oriented design, while classes should be the "nouns" or "machines."

Simply buying or building a toaster doesn't result in toast.  Someone creates the toaster (think of that as constructing an object), then they or someone else executes an operation with it to make toast (think of that as calling a method).

So, in the absence of more information, I would recommend passing the objects to the method, not the constructor.  Even if it's the same objects being passed every time.